# Copying transitive dependency in gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, maven-assembly-plugin, yajsw

I am completely newbie to Gradle so please forgive me if my question is not correct. I am using the Distribution plugin to create a ZIP file of my project. I want to implement YAJSW Wrapper service in my project. In Maven, we can use Assembly Plugin to define which dependency goes where, but in Gradle I couldn't really found a way to access each dependency separately.

I have looked everywhere, but couldn't really get a solution. I am trying to copy compile configuration's dependencies in different folders. I can include whatever I want to as long as I know the file name (since a configuration is a filecollection). But, I want to copy those transitive dependencies as well which I don't know (I know I can look for the files separately, but I don't want it to be so much of manual work). Below is a part of my code to give you an idea of what exactly I am doing right now:

```
distributions {
main {
    baseName "BaseZIP"
    contents {
        from { "src/main/resources" }            
        into('service') {
            from(project.configurations.compile) {
                include 'wrapper**'
            }
        }
        into('service/lib/core/commons') {
            from(project.configurations.compile) {
                include 'commons-cli**'
                include 'commons-collections**'
                include 'commons-configuration**'
                include 'commons-io**'
                include 'commons-logging**'
                include 'commons-vfs2**'
                include 'commons-lang**'
            }
        }}
```

Could you please help me here. It might be possible that I have missed some concept completely. I hope my questions makes sense :( Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Yes, your questions makes sense. Just a question out of personal interest: Why do you try to achieve this with Gradle if you know how to do it with Maven?

Comment: Have you considered using the Gradle application plugin instead? It takes care of all of this for you

Comment: I am sorry: @Gerold: It's not my choice. My manager wants to move to Gradle.

Comment: @tddmonkey I thought of that, but that would be adding extra features which I don't think are required for my job. I just want to pack some files and dependencies in particular structure. Again, forgive me if I am wrong, and I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: The question is more "why do you need it in that particular structure?".  If you're going to make the move to Gradle you may as well make use of its power and features

Comment: I am open to change my code in any manner, the final goal is to implement YAJSW Wrapper service. Should I look into Application plugin? Thanks!